# Solution for a complexed equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Find $z$ for the equation $e^z + e^{-z} = 0$.

So $$e^z + e^{-z} = 0 \iff e^z = -e^{-z} \iff e^z = e^{\pi i - z} \iff z = \pi i -z + 2\pi ik$$

I understand all expect the $2\pi ik$. Can you explain why the equation is true for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Because $e^{2\pi i}=1$.

Comment: It's not true for all $k\in \mathbb Z$. People writing without quantifiers... You should read it as $$e^z = e^{\pi i - z} \iff \exists k\in \mathbb Z(z = \pi i -z + 2\pi ik).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z=a+bi$, then $e^z=e^a(cos(b)+isin(b))$

Since the cos- and sin- function have periodicity $2\pi$, you get what you want.